# check for alphanumeric, space and certain special characters in String

Tags: java, regex, string

In Java, I want to check a string for alphanumeric, space and certain special characters only in String. If others found, should reject the entire string.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Pattern class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

[Regular Expression Tool](http://regexper.com/)